SQL nested xml have extra xmlns="" attribute
I am writing SQL to generate XML. This is my code:
DECLARE @inner xml = '<inner>test</inner>';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES (
    DEFAULT 'urn:www.agxml.org:schemas:all:4:0',
    'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS xsi,
    'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' AS xsd
)
SELECT
    @inner 
    FOR XML PATH('root'), TYPE

And this is what I got (line-breaks added for readability):
<root
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="urn:www.agxml.org:schemas:all:4:0"
>
  <inner xmlns="">test</inner>
</root>

You can see <inner xmlns="">test</inner> has an extra xmlns="".
I tried to remove it but I can't. Is there a way to only add xmlns to the root?

FWIW, Microsoft's docs say that you don't need to define xsi / XMLSchema-instance.

Well <inner> is not in a namespace, but you have declared a different default namespace, so what exactly do you want and why? Why does <inner> not already have the correct namespace?

The method you're using seems a little "odd", just define it all in one statement:
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (
    DEFAULT 'urn:www.agxml.org:schemas:all:4:0',
    'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS xsi,
    'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' AS xsd
)
SELECT 'test' as [inner]
FOR XML PATH('root'), TYPE;


What if it isn't possible to use 'test' AS [inner] instead of <inner>test</inner> because it's actually a T-SQL xml object from elsewhere?

Then the OP hasn't explained their problem appropriately, @Dai . They are clearly using a literal. If that data is coming from somewhere else, that information isn't volunteered or noted at all.

@Dai In which case we don't know what the correct result should be. SQL Server is techincally doing the correct thing, because <inner> in the variable is in a different namespace. If OP wants different then <inner> in the variable should already have had the correct namespace.
